# How to create multiples users with different email id using factory_girl/factory_bot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hi I am working on a Ruby on Rails project with ruby-2.5.0 and rails 5. I am using factory_bot to create user. Now I have a controller and a model to test so I want to create two users with different email id.

```
factories/users.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { 'abc1@xyz.com' }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
  end
end
```

I tried to create two records as follows:-

```
factories/users.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email, 2) { |n| "abc#{n}@xyz.com" }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
  end
end
```

But it did not create any record. Please help how can I create multiple users with different email id. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your factory:

```
factories/users.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "abc#{n}@example.com" }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
  end
end
```

And then you can write specs

```
describe User, type: :model do
  describe 'some behaviour' do
    user = build(:user)
    expect(user.do_a_thing).to have_some_effect
  end
end
```